# Installed Windows 10 through Boot Camp but it is not showing up and is taking up space

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition

I installed Windows 10 through Boot Camp on my 2015 MacBook Air. It has 150GB of storage and after restarting and holding option, the Windows partition doesn't show up. I went back into OS X and the Windows partition isn't showing up in Disk Utility. I also cannot run Boot Camp to check because it it is now asking to free up space which I already did to install Windows. How can I get Windows to show up, or how can I delete the files to reinstall it?

So apparently my storage was reduced after running Boot Camp but no Windows partition was created. How can I get this space back? I've tried running first aid on Disk Utility on start up but it did nothing.

[image]

Comment: I checked the storage and it says my mac is only using 76gb out of the 121 GB. I want to raise it back to 121 but I cant get the partition resizer from disk utility to work.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more detail, rather than add a comment or an _answer_ that isn't actually an answer.